# Spring ResponseBodyEmitter doesn't set Content-Type header in a response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm writing a kind of a wrapper around my request handlers to make them stream HTTP response. What I've got now is

**Handler response wrapper:**

```
 @Component
public class ResponseBodyEmitterProcessor {

    public ResponseBodyEmitter process(Supplier<?> supplier) {
        ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter();
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
                .execute(() -> {
                    CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier)
                            .thenAccept(result -> {
                                try {
                                    emitter.send(result, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
                                    emitter.complete();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    emitter.completeWithError(e);
                                }
                            });
                    while (!future.isDone()) {
                        try {
                            emitter.send("", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                            emitter.completeWithError(e);
                        }
                    }
                });

        return emitter;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/anything")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> getAnything() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(process(() -> {
                //long operation
            }));
}
```

What I'm doing is just send empty string every half a second to keep a request alive. It's required for some tool to not shut it down by timeout. The problem here that I don't see any **Content-Type** header in a response. There's nothing at all, despite I return ResponseEntity from my controller method as it's said in this thread:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18518

Looks like only TEXT_HTML media type is acceptable for streaming. Isn't there a way to stream json at all? I even manually mapped my dtos to json string using objectMapper, but still no luck. Tried with APPLICATION_JSON and APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON - doesn't work. Tried in different browsers - the same result.

I also manually set Content-Type header for ResponseEntity in the controller. Now there's the header in a response, but I'm not sure, if my data is actually streamed. In Chrome I can only see the result of my operation, not intermediate chars that I'm sending (changed them to "a" for test).

I checked the timing of request processing for two options:

**Without emitter (just usual controller handler)**
[image: Without emitter]

**With emitter**
[image: With emitter]

As I understand Waiting status means: "Waiting for the first byte to appear". Seems like with emitter the first byte appears much earlier - this looks like what I need. Can I consider it as a proof that my solution works?

Maybe there's another way to do it in Spring? What I need is just to notify the browser that a request is still being processed by sending some useless data to it until the actual operation is done - then return the result.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of `ResponseBodyEmitter#send` it seems that the specified `MediaType` should have been set in the `AbstractHttpMessageConverter#addDefaultHeaders` method but only when no other contentType header is already present.

```
protected void addDefaultHeaders(HttpHeaders headers, T t, MediaType contentType) throws IOException{
    if (headers.getContentType() == null) {
        MediaType contentTypeToUse = contentType;
        // ...
        if (contentTypeToUse != null) {
            headers.setContentType(contentTypeToUse);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would suggest to set a break point there and have a look why the header is not applied. Maybe the `@RestController` sets a default header.

As a workaround you could try the set the contentType header via an annotation in the MVC controller.

E.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
```

Comment: It's null when my header comes there. "produces" attribute doesn't help also. I've tried it for HTML_TEXT media type. Look at the updated code in the question.
Nice try, thanks for investigating it

Comment: Adding ```@RequestMapping(value = "/something", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)``` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just inherit from ResponseBodyEmitter, and override the method `extendResponse(ServerHttpResponse outputMessage)`, just like how `SseEmitter` does. And then use this subclass instead:

```
    public class JsonEmitter extends ResponseBodyEmitter {
        @Override
        protected void extendResponse(ServerHttpResponse outputMessage) {
            super.extendResponse(outputMessage);
            HttpHeaders headers = outputMessage.getHeaders();
            if (headers.getContentType() == null) {
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            }
        }
    }
```